# Use restTemplate getForObject when a json property name changes depending on the request

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, resttemplate

I want to use the restTemplate.getForObject method and I have got it to work when the response JSON-keys are the same for all requests. Then I used the @JsonProperty annotation and everything worked fine.

But now I have a response which always has the same structure but one of the JSON-key's name changes depending on the request I'm doing.

example

```
response 1:

{
  "entities": {
    "ID_1": { ... }
  }
}

response 2:

{
  "entities": {
    "ID_2": { ... }
  }
}
```

Since the name of ID_1 and ID_2 is not the same I can't use the @JsonProperty annotation I believe.

So my question is if I need to change the method I'm using or how I would create the DataClass which is mapped to the request. I understand that I manually could map the JSON response to an object but that feels unnecessary no?

DataClass result =  restTemplate.getForObject(url, DataClass.class);

Answer (score 0):

You could use `JsonAnySetter` `JsonAnyGetter` for the mapping, in following example additionalProperties collects all "non-mapped" properties:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Example {

    @JsonProperty("foo")
    private String foo;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();


    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```